# Embedded picture not showing in gmail body when snding mail using vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, gmail

I am trying to send a mail using gmail service(not outlook) with a picture in it's body as embedded picture using vba.

I have added Microsoft CDO Windows 2000 Library

```
Option Explicit 

Sub SendEmailUsingGmail()
    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim mailConfig As Object
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim msConfigURL As String
    Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo Err:

    'late binding
    Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set mailConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    ' load all default configurations
    mailConfig.Load -1

    Set fields = mailConfig.fields
    
    

    
  
    'Set All Email Properties
    With NewMail
        .Sender = ""
        .From = "Sourav Bhattacharya"
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Demo Spreadsheet Attached"
        .Textbody = "Let me know if you have questions about the attached spreadsheet!"
        .Addattachment "C:\Users\allso\Desktop\new vba projects\temp.jpg"
        .HTMLBody = .Textbody & "<html><p>CPS Daily progress Report of Nov 2020</p>" & _
                "<img src=""cid:temp.jpg"" height='300' width='300'>"
      
    End With

    msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"

    With fields
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True             'Enable SSL Authentication
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1          'SMTP authentication Enabled
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 'Set the SMTP server details
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465          'Set the SMTP port Details
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2                 'Send using default setting
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = "" 'Your gmail address
        .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = "" 'Your password or App Password
        .Update                                               'Update the configuration fields
    End With
    
    
    NewMail.Configuration = mailConfig
    NewMail.Send
    
    MsgBox "Your email has been sent", vbInformation

Exit_Err:
    'Release object memory
    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set mailConfig = Nothing
    End

Err:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case -2147220973  'Could be because of Internet Connection
        MsgBox "Check your internet connection." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Case -2147220975  'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
        MsgBox "Check your login credentials and try again." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Case Else   'Report other errors
        MsgBox "Error encountered while sending email." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End Select

    Resume Exit_Err

End Sub
```

I am able to send the mail and the image gets attached to the mail just fine
However in the mail body it shows blank instead of the picture

I tried searching many places,however could not find the solution

Can Someone please help

Thank You
Sourav Bhattacharya

Comment: I think it's the CID bit that could be causing the issues https://blog.mailtrap.io/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/

Comment: I managed to do it creating a html file,however still like to know the exact way without using a html file